# Multiple categories in array on Laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm using this scope for my projects:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
{{$project->subcategory}}
@endforeach
```

Every projects has multiple subcategory, so it seems like this:

```
["cat1","cat2"]
```

But I wanna see like this:

```
cat1 cat2
```

What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: can you show more info??

Comment: Run an extra for each loop to print subcategory

Comment: @DsRaj if I run an extra foreach, its getting "invalid" error.

Comment: You need to add the condition for that, check the updated answer

Comment: Personally I would change the code that produces these results and make sure that subcategroies are actually objects that get returned, and not that mix of array-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the subcategory array if you have array

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    @if(isset($project->subcategory) && !empty($project->subcategory))
        <p>
        @foreach($project->subcategory as $subcategory)
            {{ $subcategory }}
        @endforeach
        </p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**Updated**
but you have string in the subcategory, this can also be done with regex.

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    @if($project->subcategory != '')
        <p>
        {{ str_replace(['"',"[","]"],'',$project->subcategory) }}
        </p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**Updated** this regex can also be used

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9,]/', "", $project->subcategory)
```

Comment: can you paste the result of this in your question print_r($projects->toArray());

Comment: Some subcategories are empty, some categories like this:   [subcategory] => ["cat1","cat2"]

Comment: Okay it means you have such string in the subcategory

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    @if(isset($project->subcategory))
       @foreach($project->subcategory as $subcategory)
          {{ $subcategory }}
       @endforeach
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: As you shown above `$project->subcategory` is an array. Isn't it?

Comment: "subcategory": "[\"cat1\",\"cat2\"]"

Comment: What's its type? Just do `var_dump` and see.

Comment: Property [subcategory] does not exist on this collection instance.